# Parsing Erlang Config file with Python

Tags: python, parsing, erlang

I want to parse an erlang config file in python. Is there a module for it? This config file contains;

```
[{webmachine, [
 {bind_address, "12.34.56.78"},
 {port, 12345},
 {document_root, "foo/bar"}
]}].
```

Comment: why not fire off an erlang shell and let it do the formatting for you? Not in python, I know, but it will catch the corner cases and make the parsing on the python side super simple.

Comment: I dont have advice for python, but here is a posting on validating via the erl console and a unix script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423387/how-do-i-validate-an-erlang-config-file-from-a-linux-command

Answer (score 4):

Untested and a little rough, but 'works' on your example

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

input_string = """
[{webmachine, [ 
 {bind_address, "12.34.56.78"}, 
 {port, 12345}, 
 {document_root, "foo/bar"} 
]}]
"""

# make string somewhat more compatible with Python syntax:
compat = re.sub('([a-zA-Z].*?),', r'"\1":', input_string)

# evaluate as literal, see what we get
res = literal_eval(compat)

[{'webmachine': [{'bind_address': '12.34.56.78'}, {'port': 12345},
{'document_root': 'foo/bar'}]}]
```

You could then "roll-up" the list of dictionary into a simple `dict`, eg:

```
dict(d.items()[0] for d in res[0]['webmachine'])

{'bind_address': '12.34.56.78', 'port': 12345, 'document_root':
'foo/bar'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use etf library to parse erlang terms in python https://github.com/machinezone/python_etf