# How do I validate an Erlang config file from a linux command

Tags: linux, erlang

I can validate a config file with running the command

```
file:consult("settings.config").
```

Can I do this from a linux command? I know I can open the erl shell and run this command, but I want to do this with one shell command

Comment: You can use `-eval` option of `erl`.

Comment: @XiaoJia how does that work? I tried various different combinations with -eval but it always gives a syntax error. The man page was not much help either.

Comment: I was using this in my own project: `erl -sname node1 -eval "test:foobar(123)." -noinput` where `test` is a module for running different tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an escript file to do this. Something like this:

validate.escript

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
main([ConfigFile]) ->
    {ok, Terms} = file:consult(ConfigFile),
    io:format("~p~n",[Terms]).
```

Then you can invoke it from the command line:

```
./validate.escript path/to/file.config
```

Which will print the list of the terms of the config or throw an error if something went wrong.